# ubuntu 14.10 Utopic has both gstreamer 1.0 and 0.10 packages. Why?

Tags: 14.10, gstreamer

I am trying to figure out the "multimedia" stack on Ubuntu as for 14.10 release.

I have installed a lot of gstreamer0.10 packages, some are exact duplicates of 1.0 packages. Should I remove the 0.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0 and 0.10 versions are parallel installable, you can have both on your system and they don't interfere with each other.

Applications, however, can only link and use one of those versions. So, having 0.10 and/or 1.0 in your system depend on the applications you want to run and what version they were made to use. I repeat: there is no problem in having both versions installed if you have some applications that depend on 0.10 and others that depend on 1.0.

Any new code should be written for the 1.0 series, 0.10 is unmantained and obsolete for years now.